# C++ .h and .lib files to C#

Tags: c#, header

Wanted to ask a question regarding header files and lib files. 
Basically I want to create a user application in C# to communicate with an RDM/DMX compatible device.

the problem is that the library and header files are generated by C++. 
I would like to know if I will be able to use the functions withing these files to communicate with the device using C#?

Secondly, if there are any other alternatives then please let me know if I am barking up the wrong tree. XD
cheers.
Labmat

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't easily work with .lib files. One method would be to build the C++ library into a WinRT DLL. C# can work with those.

Comment: do you have any examples I could look into?

Comment: You'll need to build is a "Windows Runtime Component (Universal App)" project in Visual Studio. It generates a template of a simple WinRT C++ class you can built your stuff from. Then you reference that component DLL into your C# project and the class will be available to use.